# Why is Pandas ignoring doublequote=True when reading a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with data like this:

```
123,"this is text",123,123,123,"""This is text, it is quoted and has a comma"""
```

I'm reading this CSV file with `pandas`, and this row should be interpreted as:

```
col1 |     col2     | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6
123  | this is text | 123  | 123  | 123  | "This is text, it is quoted and has a comma"
```

However, I keep getting

> expected N columns but found N+1 in row number ....

errors from `pandas`.

I tested this in a docker container in my local machine, same python and `pandas` versions that are in the server, in my machine it works fine, but on the server, it doesn't.

This is the command I am using in both cases:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_path, dtype=str, sep=',', keep_default_na=True, quotechar='"', doublequote=True)
```

If I change doublequote to `False` in my local docker container then I get that same error, but with `True` it works, but on the server, it works with neither `False` nor `True`, it would seem doublequote is doing nothing.

One difference I can see is the GCC python uses, on the server it says GCC 4.8.5 and on my local docker container it says GCC 8.3.0, could that be the issue? And if it is, how do specify that on the server?

Comment: The GCC version could hardly be relevant. C doesn't have any CSV parsing functions.

Comment: And your version of GCC doesn't matter unless you recompile pandas.

Comment: Ugh, turns out this had nothing to do with pandas, there was a previous component that was incorrectly transforming double quotes and it broke CSV standard    -_-

Answer (score 0):

I just created two files with the information you provided (a .csv and a .txt file). Both approaches work for me.

```py
pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)
```

Maybe you could try another version of pandas. Mine is 1.2.5 and it works as expected.